# Recursive Euclidean GCD algorithm with function

Tags: python

I'm asking about the recursive part I have to display (and in a function with another argument `verbose: bool`).
I need to calculate the gcd of two numbers.
But how I can display the quotient and the rest and the opertions?

Like this:

```
By setting q the quotient of the integer division of a by b, let us calculate for example
the gcd of 90 and of 35 (gcd (90,35), so a = 90 and b = 35):
  a = b × q + r
As for 90/35 we have q = 2 and r = 20, then 90 = 35 × 2 + 20
According to Euclid, pgcd (90.35) = pgcd (35.20). So we start over with the new values:
  35 = 20 × 1 + 15
According to Euclid, pgcd (35.20) = pgcd (20.15). So we start over with the new values:
  20 = 15 × 1 + 5
According to Euclid, pgcd (20.15) = pgcd (15.5). So we start over with the new values:
  15 = 5 × 3 + 0
15 is divisible by 5 so we stop and pgcd (15.5) = pgcd (20.15) = pgcd (35.20) =
pgcd (90.35) = 5

Write the code of the euclid function (a: int, b: int, verbose: bool = False) -> int which
calculates the gcd of a and b and, if the verbose parameter is True, displays the
different steps of the algorithm of the calculation (the values ​​of a, b, q and r).
```

I tried this but this is complete, I don't know anything about this.
I don't even know what's the order of what.

What I've tried:

```py
def gcd(a,b, verbose = False):
    r = a%b
    q:int

    if r == 0:
        q = a//b
        print(b)
        return b
    else:
        verbose = True
        while r != 0:
            result = b*q+r
            a= result
            b = result
            r = b
        return result

num1 = int(input('chose a number'))
num2 = int(input('chose a second number'))

print(gcd(num1,num2, verbose = False))
```

Here's the output:

[image: output]

"before assignment" yes, but according to the problem I don't know where to put `q` except in `if r== 0` then `q = a//b`.

And I don't know how to make the recursive part how I'm supposed to loop on `a = b*q + r` and say that if `r` is not `0` then `a` is `b` and `b` is `r` and to do it until `r` is `0` and print the gcd, if `verbose` is `True` I have to describe each calculation and print `a`,`b`,`r`, and `q`.

Comment: There's no recursion in your function.

Comment: You shouldn't ever assign `verbose = True`. You're supposed to test the `verbose` flag. If it's true, you print the steps as you do them, otherwise you do them silently.

Comment: You are using q in the else statement without providing it a value.

Comment: Please try to post like an adult, without the harsh language.

Comment: FYI there is no need to fill your question with text telling people not to close your question - your question needs to be written with enough detail and clarity that it's not closed (and if you write a question that doesn't fit here, it might still be closed, regardless of your plea)

Comment: Okok... I edited

Comment: The thing is I don't know about recursion like i'm suposed to use a loop ? But how I loop and say that in the next a= b*q + r the a is the b and the b is the r

Comment: I edited too - I removed your plea to not close, along with mention of other SO questions - that doesn't help your question at all. What's left is the assignment, and some code, without any clarity around the problem you're having with your code. Please edit to be very specific, along with information about your code: errors, inputs, expected vs actual outputs, etc.

Comment: But it's clear... I don't know how to make recursive euclidian function and especially the recursive part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment doesn't say you have to use recursion and, in fact, it's simpler if you don't and use iteration (i.e. a loop) instead.

Here's what I mean:

```
def gcd(a: int, b: int, verbose: bool = False) -> int:
    while b != 0:
        if verbose:
            print(f'{a=}, {b=}')
        q = a // b
        r = a % b
        a = b
        b = r
    return a

#num1 = int(input('chose a number'))
#num2 = int(input('chose a second number'))
num1, num2 = 90, 35  # Hardcode for testing.
print(f'gcd({num1}, {num2}, verbose=True)={gcd(num1, num2, verbose=True)}')
```

Output:

```
a=90, b=35
a=35, b=20
a=20, b=15
a=15, b=5
gcd(90, 35, verbose=True)=5
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a recursive approach in following fashion:

```
def gcd(a,b,verbose=False):
    if b>a:
        return gcd(b,a,verbose)
    r=a%b
    if r==0:
        if verbose==True:
            q=a//b
            print("a=",a,"b=",b,"q=",q,"r=",r)
        return b
    else:
        if verbose==True:
            q=a//b
            print("a=",a,"b=",b,"q=",q,"r=",r)
        return gcd(b,r,verbose)
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this and give a feedback

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works Thanks !